# Extracting values from words and numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms, char

Hey i'm fairly new to programming, so my wording may not be the best but,

I need to know how to display an output in textbox that shows only specific selected letters from input of a word in the same textbox

for example user inputs Maria Fernandez 123456789 > presses a button and the output would be > MF789

regardless of whether the input in uppercase or not?

```
private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        MessageBox.Show(txtF.Text + " " + txtL.Text+" ,Right");
        txtFull.Text = txtF.Text+" "+txtL.Text;
        txtInfo.Text = txtF.Text. + txtL.Text+ txtCode.Text;
```

this is the code i'm working with right now

Comment: It's not really clear what logic you want your program to apply to the inputted text- take the first characters of any textual strings and the last three of any numeric strings? Please edit your question to explain what it is you would like to do with the string exactly. That being said, there are many examples of string manipulation on this site and others. Some quick research should set you on the right path.

Comment: so are you basically wanting to get `First Initial` of First Name and `First Initial` of Last Name plus Last 3 characters of their Social Security Number for example..? if so this is extremely simple are you familiar with the SubString() function...? and you can also implement this using the Split() Function along with SubString()

Comment: Yeah, i tried using it before but i was having problems intlength when i was dealing with the "social insurance input values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the default Split() method which would be spaces you could do the following as well

```
string name = "Maria Fernandez 123456789";
var intials = name.Split();
var finalInitials = intials[0].Substring(0, 1) + 
      intials[1].Substring(0, 1) + 
      intials[2].Substring(intials[2].Length - 3);
```

or you can specify the " " as the Split delimiter like this

```
string name = "Maria Fernandez 123456789";
var intials = name.Split(new [] {" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var finalInitials = intials[0].Substring(0, 1) + 
       intials[1].Substring(0, 1) + 
       intials[2].Substring(intials[2].Length - 3);
```

> Both of these will yield the same result finalInitials = "MF789"

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
string name = "Maria Fernandez 123456789";

int firstSpace = name.IndexOf(" ");
string initials = (name.Substring(0, 1) + name.Substring(firstSpace + 1, 1) + name.Substring(name.Length - 3)).ToUpper();
```

`initials` would equal "MF789"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner, assuming no irregular data:

```
s.Split(new[] {' '}).Aggregate((r, p) => r += (Char.IsNumber(p[0]) ? p.Substring(p.Length - 3) : p[0].ToString()));
```

Edit: shortened lambda names, formatting.